# Custom Middleware Laravel is not working on api routes

Tags: php, laravel

i had middleware call user which is to filter a role on my user table on database. this is my middleware called user

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Auth;
use UsersData;
class User
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if(Auth::check() && Auth::User()->role=='user'){
            return $next($request);
        }
        return redirect()->route('login')->with('danger',"You don't have an access");
    }
}
```

and i already register my middleware in kernel

```
protected $routeMiddleware = [
        'auth' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authenticate::class,
        'auth.basic' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\AuthenticateWithBasicAuth::class,
        'bindings' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
        'can' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authorize::class,
        'guest' => \App\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfAuthenticated::class,
        'throttle' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ThrottleRequests::class,
        'user' => \App\Http\Middleware\User::class,
        'ajax' => \App\Http\Middleware\Ajax::class,
    ];
```

and the routes of `api.php`

```
Route::middleware('user')->group(function () {
        Route::post('province','ApiController@getcity')->name('api.getcity');
        Route::post('courier/getcost','ApiController@getCourierCost')->name('api.getcouriercost');
    });
```

update on `config/auth.php` here is the guards

```
<?php

return [

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Authentication Defaults
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This option controls the default authentication "guard" and password
    | reset options for your application. You may change these defaults
    | as required, but they're a perfect start for most applications.
    |
    */

    'defaults' => [
        'guard' => 'web',
        'passwords' => 'users',
    ],

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Authentication Guards
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Next, you may define every authentication guard for your application.
    | Of course, a great default configuration has been defined for you
    | here which uses session storage and the Eloquent user provider.
    |
    | All authentication drivers have a user provider. This defines how the
    | users are actually retrieved out of your database or other storage
    | mechanisms used by this application to persist your user's data.
    |
    | Supported: "session", "token"
    |
    */

    'guards' => [
        'web' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],

        'api' => [
            'driver' => 'token',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],
    ],

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | User Providers
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | All authentication drivers have a user provider. This defines how the
    | users are actually retrieved out of your database or other storage
    | mechanisms used by this application to persist your user's data.
    |
    | If you have multiple user tables or models you may configure multiple
    | sources which represent each model / table. These sources may then
    | be assigned to any extra authentication guards you have defined.
    |
    | Supported: "database", "eloquent"
    |
    */

    'providers' => [
        'users' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\User::class,
        ],

        // 'users' => [
        //     'driver' => 'database',
        //     'table' => 'users',
        // ],
    ],

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Resetting Passwords
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | You may specify multiple password reset configurations if you have more
    | than one user table or model in the application and you want to have
    | separate password reset settings based on the specific user types.
    |
    | The expire time is the number of minutes that the reset token should be
    | considered valid. This security feature keeps tokens short-lived so
    | they have less time to be guessed. You may change this as needed.
    |
    */

    'passwords' => [
        'users' => [
            'provider' => 'users',
            'table' => 'password_resets',
            'expire' => 60,
        ],
    ],

];
```

everything works on `web.php` routes but this `api.php` is not working ?

i really appreciate if you comment it !

Comment: Could you regard your `config/auth.php` settings?

Comment: Also, how are you accessing these routes? Possibly with an ajax call?

Comment: @SaidbakR updated on my post

Comment: You're using `session` driver for authenticating and the `api` routes don't use sessions. Is there any reason why you have those routes in `api`? The easiest solution is just to move them to `web`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the reason we have separate route files for web (web.php) and API (api.php) is because they use different method of authentication. First one is the usual way ([Web Auth](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/authentication)) and the second is [API Auth](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/passport) which already mentioned by @Babak on his/her answer.

API authentication is stateless which requires token on each request which is generated and recorded on separate table with `user_id` as its `foreign key`. There is no login page for authenticating API users, but you can use the usual login page to let them request `API Token` and use it for accessing the API. You can use various ways to check their `API Token` validation such as put it on `request header` as `Bearer`, or include it on `request body`, etc.

Answer (score 3):

in ajax requests you can`t check auth like this:

```
Auth::check();
```

because in ajax you have not any sessions.
you have to send a random key for each user when it sends first request to login and when login succeed, save it in key field in database of him after that when ever he wants to send request he has to send the key with, and you will check the key with the one in database if its ok let him in.

Comment: Very Good Note!